# C++ on MacOS POD-type checking

Tags: c++, macos, variadic-functions

I have the following C++ function:

```
using namespace std;

template<typename ... Args>

string string_format( const std::string& format, Args ... args )
{
    size_t size = snprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ...) + 1; 
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] ); 
    snprintf( buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args ... );
    return string( buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1 ); 
}
```

I'm able to compile it on a Windows environment. If I try on MacOS, using `gcc`, I get the following error:

> cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'std::__1::basic_string'
>   through variadic function; call will abort at runtime
>   [-Wnon-pod-varargs]

gcc setup is as following (`gcc --version`):

> **Configured with** 
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr 
>   --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 
>   **Apple LLVM version:** 
>   10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5) 
>   **Target:** x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0 
>   **Thread model** posix 
>   **InstalledDir:**
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

I guess that there should be some options for gcc to avoid POD-type checking that I'm not aware of.

Did someone else run into the same issue?

### **UPDATE**

Example code that call the `string_format` function:

```
class Node
{
public:
  int id;
  int reference;
  int value;
  std::string label;

  std::string describe()
  {
     return string_format("%s %ld %ld %ld", label, id, reference, value);
  } 
}
```

Comment: That's an old gcc compiler. Try with a new one (VS is also a new version?)

Comment: can you give us a full working example causing the error, it seems to me that the error pointed is not int the code you gave...

Comment: Yes, what are you calling `string_format` *with*?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher its not gcc at all; its Apple's customized clang.

Comment: you did not post the code showing how you are using the template

Comment: I updated the post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` format specifier is for a CString. You are passing a `std::string`. It will work if you do this instead: `string_format("%s %ld %ld %ld", label.c_str(), id, reference, value);`